# d3.js packing bubble chart elements

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js

I am trying to use the bubble chart example as a template to build a visualisation. I have my JSON as a flat-hierarchy, such that there is one element called `children` and that holds an array of objects that I want to visualise.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "children":[
    {
      "acc":"Q15019",
      "uid":"SEPT2_HUMAN",
      "sym":"SEPT2",
      "name":"Septin-2",
      "alt_ids":"",
      "ratio":0.5494271087884398,
      "pval":0.990804718
    },
    ...,
    {
      "acc":"Q16181",
      "uid":"SEPT7_HUMAN",
      "sym":"SEPT7",
      "name":"Septin-7",
      "alt_ids":"",
      "ratio":1.1949912048567823,
      "pval":0.511011887
    }
  ]
}
```

I have modified the example code as follows:

```
var diameter = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scale.quantile().range(colorbrewer.RdBu[9]);

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr("class", "bubble");

d3.json("datagraph.json", function(datagraph) {
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(datagraph))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.acc; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  //node.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return 30; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
        if(d.ratio == null)
          return "#ffffff";
        else
          return color(d.ratio); 
      });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".3em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.acc; });
});
```

The resultant HTML has a ton of `<g>` tags responding to each element except they are never translated to the right position, but instead sort of sit on top of each other on the top left corner. By investigating in Firebug, I figured this happens presumably because the pack() algorithm does not get the objects one at a time, but the whole array as a single element, thus individual elements don't get .x and .y values.

[image]

If I change the `.nodes()` argument to `datagraph.children` I get the elements one at a time in nodes() iteration, but oddly enough I get a single `<g>` object. Since I don't need to flatten a hierarchy I skipped the `classes(root)` function, in the example. What I am wondering is whether or not the `packageName` attribute plays any role in the nodes()?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show what your json looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a [value accessor](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout#value):

```
var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
  .sort(null)
  .size([diameter, diameter])
  .padding(1.5)
  .value(function(d) { return d.pval; }) //<- must return a number
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENDa8OGLx09hgXMb6C8H?p=preview).

Comment: @posdef, the default is to look for a `value` property which you don't have.  The code you link to adds a `value` property in the `classes` function.